# Powerbank for bicycle helmet mounted cameras

Tags: power-bank

I'm looking for a power bank to extend the capacity of my action cam battery.

Requirements:

- Small enough to mount on a bicycle helmet
- Its shape fits well to bicycle helmets
- Possible/easy to mount on a helmet
- At least 1000mAh capacity

Nice to have features:

- No need to power on, always on (I don't want two handle two power buttons, the one on the camera is enough)
- Easy to mount/unmount (umount for shorter rides, or using more than one for longer rides)

Comment: How are you going to attach it to your helmet? Would using Velcro be ok? What helmet do you have?

Comment: @Cfinley: Velcro is ok for me. It's something like this one: http://www.bellhelmets.com/en_eu/cycling/helmets/recreational/xlp

Comment: Would charging your action cam over USB work?

Comment: @Cfinley: Yes, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found that most power banks (and laptop batteries) use 18650 Li-Ion batteries (cells).

So finally I bought a 18650 battery case (search for "18650 power bank case") which I'm using with a 18650 cell from a disassembled old laptop battery. Currently this one:

[image]

Product link and image source: [2600mAh 5V 1A USB Power Bank Case Charger DIY Box For iPhone](http://www.banggood.com/2600mAh-5V-1A-USB-Power-Bank-Case-Charger-DIY-Box-For-iPhone-p-969623.html)

> Small enough to mount on a bicycle helmet
>   Its shape fits well to bicycle helmets

It's not perfect, but it seems to be the best option currently.
Mine weights 67 grams (including battery).

> Possible/easy to mount on a helmet

With self-adhesive velcro it works fine.

> At least 1000mAh capacity

18650 batteries usually have 2600+mAh capacity.

> No need to power on, always on (I don't want two handle two power buttons, the one on the camera is enough)

I have not tested it thoughtfully but mine does not have any power button and seems fine.

> Easy to mount/unmount (unmount for shorter rides, or using more than one for longer rides)

Velcro solves that.